# Ifelse within dplyr taking a longer time to execute

Tags: r, medical

I am working on medical claims data and the data file is as showcased below

```
claim_id  status
abc123    P
abc123    R
xyz374    P
xyz386    R
```

I would like to create a new column as flag which will basically group by claim_id and if the status for the same claim_id includes both "P" and "R". The flag column should include "Yes"

```
claim_id  status  flag
abc123    P       Yes
abc123    R       Yes
xyz374    P       No
xyz386    R       No
```

My approach to this solution is using dplyr :-

```
data <-data1 %>% 
   group_by(claim_id)%>% 
   mutate(flag = ifelse(any(status == "P" | status == "R"), 
                            "Yes", 
                             as.character(status)))
```

This approach takes a longer time and also marks all the rows as Yes in flag column.

Comment: What happens  if you remove the `any`?

Comment: I get this error - Error: argument "yes" is missing, with no default

Comment: Why `as.character(status)` if you want `"No"` as an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
data1 <- data1 %>% group_by(claim_id) %>% mutate(flag = (n_distinct(status) == 2))
```

This one assumes that those are the only two possible values for the status field. If that is not true, you will need to something like this:

```
data1 <- data1 %>% group_by(claim_id) %>% mutate(flag = (('P' %in% status) & ('R' %in% status)))
```

---

You can also do

```
data1 %>% 
  group_by(claim_id) %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(all(c("P", "R") %in% status), "Yes", "No"))
```

However, it might be even better to use a logical flag. It avoids the `ifelse` altogether (making it faster) and makes subsetting really easy afterwards:

```
data1 %>% 
  group_by(claim_id) %>% 
  mutate(flag = all(c("P", "R") %in% status))
```

Comment: The first solution works. But thank you for the alternative one as well.